# Set color on button click, like select unselect color change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, sass

I am trying to use Avatar of ant d as multipikcer button, But I want to change color when I select any one of them.

```
  const weekDays = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "ST"];

return 
(<>{weekly && (
        <div>{weekDays.map((days, index) => selectedWeekdays(days))}</div>
      )}</>)



const selectWeekDays = (day) => {
    let wD = weekday;
    let index = wD.findIndex((d) => d === day);
    if (index > -1) {
      wD.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      wD.push(day);
    }
    setWeekday(wD);
  };

  const selectedWeekdays = (days) => {
    let index = weekday.findIndex((d) => days.value === d);
    let changeColor = (Style["background-color"] = "#FFFFFF");

    if (index > -1) {
      changeColor = Style["background-color"] = "#ffffff";
    }

    return (
      <Avatar
        id={days}
        onClick={() => selectWeekDays(days)}
        className={changeColor && Style["week-days"]}
        key={days}
      >
        {days}
      </Avatar>
    );
  };
```

and this is the SCSS file for this

```
.week-days {
  border: "1px solid #000000";
  display: "flex";
  align-items: "center";
  color: "#000000";
  height: 55;
  cursor: "pointer";
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

Not the point is I am not able to change the color on select. Other logic is working expected
But not color chaning.

So initially it have white background, and black text, and when I pick on it, it gets selected and color change to blue background and white text.

But instead from above code I am getting this output

no, white color is getting set, and no color is changing on selecting button.

Also below is what I expect..

Can someone help me with this?? what I am  doing wrong?

Comment: can you reproduce this in https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy maybe check this https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dream-7p3hw?file=/src/App.js  (not exactly the same, but you can relate-- check console logs too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use JavaScript to toggle style classes

This simple JavaScript two lines paired with a CSS class, will change the colours as desired.

```js
const dayElement = document.getElementById(day);
dayElement.classList.toggle("selected-day");
```

```css
.selected-day {
  background: magenta;
  color: white;
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-easley-ugl1i?file=/src/App.js

If you have any questions or suggestion please don't hesitate to ask.